Reinstall systemd or networkmanager
I upgraded to 24.04 before the August (2024) .1 first point release and it destroyed internet connectivity. I posted the question here Upgraded to 24.04, ethernet adaptor stuck at "getting IP configuration".
Unfortunately nobody has been able to advise successfully. I posted the following follow-up question in September:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527654/reinstall-systemd-or-networkmanager
but I only got around to reviewing responses after the post was deleted 5 days ago. Basically, I want to make a bootable Ubuntu 24.04.1 (Desktop) ISO USB drive, boot from this drive as live media then use that system to chroot to my existing install and attempt to reinstall either networkmanager alone, or systemD alone. Then I guess I would boot from the installed Ubuntu and if internet is restored I can download updates. I would be very grateful for instructions on how to do this.
I am alternatively thinking about a clean install but I am super worried about losing data or settings by either not backing up properly or not restoring properly. In DejaDup I tried backing up /home to a 124 GB USB drive but it failed because it requires 667 GB for some reason (my documents are probably only a few MB). I don't even know if DejaDup is the preferred backup utility that would meet the need of a comprehensive restore. I don't know what I should back up in order to fully restore (not whole of "home" folder? Anything else?).
Sorry, I am not super knowledgable.
UPDATE1: Can I please get step-by-step backup instructions?
UPDATE2: For backup I am tied to DejaDup since without internet I cannot install any software.
Thanks a lot, Paul

You do know the ISOs contain a squashfs that is a file-system image which gets expanded onto disk... ie. it's not packages that are installed one by one to create an installed image (that would take far longer!) so what you're asking about would require you to generate an ISO that contains .deb files since that's what you seem to expect...  Did you read the comments in your prior links?  If you decompressed the squashfs, you'll get files that would get written to your file-system, where a single deb package consists of many files existing in many locations!

ie.   on the ISO I'm betting you're expecting https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble-updates/systemd or the DEB package, where instead you'll get what's seen on this link https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble-updates/amd64/systemd/filelist or the many files that are installed by that package...  (assuming your architecture etc match my links!) ...  You'll note it's a rather long list of files for just a single DEB package...   The ISOs are built for system installs, not what you're hoping to do with them.

Advice: Figure out your backup problem, it's easier. Then reinstall. The chrooting approach to repair your networking seems fraught with a lot of maybes and hopefullys. You're not required to backup using DejaDup, Use whatever tool you best understand.

Reinstall using "something else", the current layout and  WITHOUT fornatting. That will keep all persona; software and manually edited settings. You will need to reinstall softeware you added and remove what you removed.
